# When does a modification of GPL code stop being one?

Tags: licensing, gpl

By the GPL v2, every modification of the program needs to be licensed by the GPL as well:

> "*... by modifying or distributing the Program (or any work based on the
>   Program), you indicate your acceptance of this License to do so, and
>   all its terms and conditions for copying, distributing or modifying
>   the Program or works based on it.*"

However, at some point, a large enough modification stops being a modification - if you changed code that sorts numbers to one that uploads files to the cloud, I'd assume the original license is no longer relevant.

The question becomes, when is a modification large enough to stop being guided by the GPL? This is especially relevant with code that's has large portions of boilerplate, such as GLib code - when creating new code, you are quite likely to base your code on a similar already written source, while retaining the boilerplate and replacing the core functionality. Is this type of code still considered to be a modification under the GPL? Where can one find guidelines or historical precedents that can help guide a decision on whether one needs to retain the original license or not?

Comment: This issue is not specific for GPL but concerns all instances of copyrighted code: How much can you change before it is a completely different work and not covered by the copyright of the original work? I don't know the answer (and I think it is a tricky legal issue!), but if this is a real-world concern for you, I strongly recommend writing a "clean room" implementation, rather than starting out with copyrighted code.

Comment: You're essentially asking for the definition of a *derived work* as per copyright law. The definition is often subject to extremely high-stake legal battles, so it's unsurprising that it's extremely disputed. The popular "clean-room implementation" defense is intended to demonstrate *beyond the shadow of  doubt* that somthing is *not* a derived work, but that doesn't mean that everything else *is* a derived work. It's just a means for companies to make sure they aren't caught somewhere in the disputed territory.

Comment: There's some precedent for such modifications in the [history of the BSD family of operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution#Net.2F2_and_legal_troubles), though of course that is entirely unrelated to the GPL. The original Unix source code was non-free and owned by AT&T. The complete system was rewritten on a file by file basis so that the history of each file didn't include AT&T-copyrighted parts (possible because copyright protects expression, not ideas). Of course that resulted in a lawsuit that was only settled after multiple years of uncertainty.

Comment: Voting to close as this is a legal question around licences and copyright, so is off-topic here.

Answer (score 10):

When the court in the lawsuit says so. That is the ultimate standard by which decisions like this are made.

In your example of taking boilerplate code and plugging in your functionality, if the boilerplate remains recognizable, the court is very likely to still consider it a modification. They don't know or care what parts of the code is and isn't "boilerplate".

This is exactly why big companies who are developing code that is known to be vulnerable to lawsuits because there is an existing implementation to people could accuse you of copying (especially in cases where you'Re reverse engineering it) will do a [clean room implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design) by very explicitly prohibiting the developers to so much as *look* at the code they might be accused of copying.

Comment: I'd agree in cases that code is doing the same thing. Is this also the case where the purpose of the code is different? Say, developing a plugin that does Y instead of X for a given system? In this case, the boilerplate is likely to be very similar between all plugins, yet different plugins can do very different things.

Comment: Regarding your boilerplate, go and read about Goolgle vs. Oracle in their Java API lawsuit.

Comment: @nbubis: If you copied the boilerplate from a licensed file, then you are creating a derivative work. If you came up with it on your own (even if it happens to be completely similar) you are creating an original work.

Comment: @nbubis: if you can convince the court that the boilerplate is the same because there is really no other way to write it, then you're good. You might have to get an expert witness to testify so.

Answer (score 2):

Compare it with writing a scientific article. If you have written everything by yourself, but just by chance used the same wording in a few minor parts, without knowledge of it - you can't be blamed. If however you have knowledge of it being the same, because you are using this sentence as source, you are obliged to mark it as a quote.

The same goes with GPL code. As soon as it is not coincidence that you have some lines in common (e.g. `for (int i; i <= limit; ++i)` is probably a quite common line in most projects, without being copied from anywhere), but you really copied lines knowingly, you need to honor it - which means, you need to license it under GPL, too.

In court, it depends on, if the code you used is licensable at all. You can't license something, where you can't claim any rights, such as the copyright. So there is the concept of *threshold of originality* which needs to be decided for every single case. If the copied lines are to trivial (in sum, not each by itself!) it might be considered, not to be protected by copyright. As then, no one could claim the copyright, this part can't be licensed, because there is no one who holds the rights needed. But this is something very delicate and needs to be determined individually for each case. It also might be different from country to country.

Just *recently* there has been a [high-profile-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_America,_Inc._v._Google,_Inc.) Goodle vs. Oracle, you might have heard of, where it has been only about the *API* - which you could consider your boilerplate?

To sum it up: You are on the safe side, if you relicense it under a compatible license.

Answer (score 0):

Code is GPL licensed if someone licenses it under the GPL.

You can change one word, and not license it, and it is not GPL licensed. Since your code is a derived work, you don't have any right to distribute it unless you follow the license of the code that isn't yours, so to distribute it you must put it under the GPL license, but of course you don't *have* to distribute it. (Unlike plain copyright, GPL allows you to *create* modified works).

There is no requirement to license under GPL as soon as there is no code left that isn't yours but was given to you under the GPL license. 90% your code = needs license. 99.99% your code = needs license. 100% your code = needs no license.

Comment: Every program in some langauge contains a lot of code that is similar (has same words, lines, patterns) as some other code. Saying any code that's 99.99% different is still a modification simply isn't reasonable.

Comment: @nbubis: It is not just a question of similarity. If you independently write some code which accidentally happens to be 100% similar to some other copyrighted code, you have still created an original work. But if you copy parts from some copyrighted work, you are creating a derivative, unless the copied parts are really insignificant - and that would be up to judge to decide.

Comment: However, if you did (by some miracle) produce a non-trivial piece of software that was 100% identical to a copyrighted work, you would have difficulty convincing the judge / jury that you didn't copy it.  (If the software was trivially small, the judge may well accept the *de minimis* argument.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually very simple: **it doesn't.  Period.**

The GPL was deliberately designed to spread to every bit of code it touches in any way as much as possible; later revisions to the license have been made with the intention of filling loopholes and closing workarounds to this "feature".  It's been called a "viral" license for this reason: because it spreads and "infects" everything it comes into contact with.

It's important to understand that the GPL was created for ideological reasons.  Richard Stallman is philosophically opposed to the very concept of proprietary software.  He wishes it would go extinct entirely, and the GPL is his mechanism for doing so, by attempting to crowd it out and make it increasingly difficult, as time goes by, to write good software without using GPL code in some place in your project.

Therefore, at what point is something so far modified from its GPL roots that it stops being subject to the GPL?  Never, because at every point along the way, the modifications become subject to the GPL too.  Really the only good way to not get the license restrictions on your codebase is to avoid your project ever touching the viral license in the first place.

Comment: Really? even if I `rm` the original file and replace it with totally different code?

Comment: Stallmans ideology is totally irrelevant to the legal question. He will not be the judge in the case. The question is not what the GPL license states, the question is if the work in question is covered by the GPL license or not.

Comment: @JacquesB It's very relevant, because it was the guiding principle in the crafting of the legal language that makes up the license to be interpreted by the hypothetical judge and jury you're positing here.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: The question is if the work is a derived work or an original work. This is a question of copyright law, not about individual licenses. It would be the same issue if I took a novel and rewrote it extensively and then claimed it was an original work.

Comment: The guiding principle, that can't be met. Because - depending on the country - some parts of the code can't be copyrighted. Without a right, you can't license it. So your statement describs only the intention, but is overly-broad, when it comes to the limits to what can be licensed at all.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: The wording of the GPL license is irrelevant because while a license can state conditions for derivative works, it cannot define what counts as a derivative work in the first place. (If it could, someone could write a license which claimed any code written in the future by anybody is actually a derivative of this file)